# Confirming a processed payment with PayPal in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating PayPal into my website and need to know how I can confirm that a payment has been processed or not.

I need PayPal to send me a response via PHP get that confirms the payment. Is there an option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the "Completing the Express Checkout Transaction" section of this page.  After you send the request, PayPal will send an NVP response including the transaction ID.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration

If you aren't using the Express Checkout API, and instead using Website Payments Pro, there is documentation at the link on the left-hand side that details that.

If you have a more specific question, feel free to comment. :)